# Sound-Reactive css animation on chrome android/iOs

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, mobile

I'm working on a website for my Sound Design degree for which I need to visualize the music.
I managed to animate the background of my website according to the "volume" of the sound playing (variation of the opacity). It works like a charm on Chrome osx but I can't can't figure out how to make it work on android/iOS. Should I use a specific library for mobile css animation ?

Thanks a lot !!

Here is the messy my code in his entirety :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Choir_Test</title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <style>
        body {
         font-family:'Open Sans', serif; font-size:40px;
         background-color:#000000;
         padding : 0;
         margin: 0;
         width: 100%; 
         height: 100%;      
         }

        Header {
            position: center 40px;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            color: white;
        }

        .contentWrapper { 
        width:1000px; margin-left: 40px; font-size:22px; font-weight:200;
        }

        h1 { 
        font-size:60px; font-weight:300;
        }

        .area { 
            height: 150px;
            width: 100%;
            color: white;
            z-index:10;
            padding : 0;
            margin: 0;
        }



        #circularCenter { 
        margin: auto; 
        position: absolute; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0; 
        bottom: 0; 
        right: 0; 
        width:74px; 
        height:74px; 
        border-radius:100%; 
        background:rgb(255,0,0); 
        }
        .circle {  
        background:rgba(255,0,0, 1); 
        position: absolute; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0; 
        bottom: 0; 
        right: 0; 
        -webkit-transition:0.1s ease all; 
        z-index:-1;
        }

        .initiator {
        position:absolute;
        width:100%; height:100%; 
        background:rgba(255,255,255, 0);
        -webkit-transition:0.3s ease all;
        z-index:1;
        cursor:pointer;
        }

.experiment { 
background:rgba(0,0,0, 1);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#000,#000);
background:-moz-linear-gradient(#000,#000);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(#000,#000); 
width:100%; 
height:100%; 
position: center 40px;
background-image:url(Images/Choirs.png);
background-size:150px 75px;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center 40px;
z-index: 100;
height: 100%;
Width: 100%;
padding : 0;
margin: 0;
 }


.header
{
height: 100px;
padding-right: auto; 
padding-left:auto;
z-index: 1000;
}



.footer
{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
height: 30px;
padding-left:40px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
z-index: 750;
-webkit-filter: invert(100%);
}

    </style>

</head>

<body>

        <div class="experiment" id="r3">
                <div class="initiator"></div>
            <div id="circles" class="area"></div>
            <div id="circles" class="footer">
            <a href="http://twitter.com"><img src="Images/Twitter.png" width="40px"></img></a>
            <a href="http://facebook.com"><img src="Images/Facebook.png" width="40px"></img></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <audio id="r0audio" loop>
        <source src="Musics/China1.mp3"></audio>

    <script>
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.mozAudioContext;

        var renderers = {
            'r0': (function() {
                var barsArr = [],
                    initialized = false,
                    barsEl;

                var height = 0;

                var init = function(config) {
                    var count = config.count;
                    var width = config.width;
                    var barWidth = (width/count) >> 0;
                    height = config.height;

                    barsEl = document.getElementById('bars');
                    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++ ){
                        var nunode = document.createElement('div');
                        nunode.classList.add('bar');
                        nunode.style.width = barWidth + 'px';
                        nunode.style.left = (barWidth * i) + 'px';
                        barsArr.push(nunode);
                        barsEl.appendChild(nunode);
                    }
                    initialized = true;
                };
                var max = 256;

                var renderFrame = function(frequencyData) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < barsArr.length; i++) {
                        var bar = barsArr[i];
                        bar.style.height = ((frequencyData[i]/max)*height + 'px');
                    }
                };


                return {
                    init: init,
                    isInitialized: function() {
                        return initialized;
                    },
                    renderFrame: renderFrame
                }
            })(),

            'r3': (function() {
                var circles = [];
                var initialized = false;
                var height = 0;
                var width = 0;

                var init = function(config) {
                    var count = config.count;
                    width = config.width;

                    height = config.height;
                    var circleMaxWidth = (width*0.99) >> 0;
                    circlesEl = document.getElementById('circles');
                    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++ ){
                        var node = document.createElement('div');
                        node.style.width = node.style.color = (i/count*circleMaxWidth) + 'px';
                        node.classList.add('circle');
                        circles.push(node);
                        circlesEl.appendChild(node);
                    }
                    initialized = true;
                };
                var max = 256;

                var renderFrame = function(frequencyData) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
                        var circle = circles[i];
                        circle.style.cssText = '-webkit-transform:scale('+1+');';
                        circle.style.cssText += 'opacity:'+((frequencyData[i]/max))+';';

                    }
                };



                return {
                    init: init,
                    isInitialized: function() {
                        return initialized;
                    },
                    renderFrame: renderFrame
                }
            })(),
                    };

        window.onload = function() {

            function Visualization(config) {
                var audio,
                    audioStream,
                    analyser,
                    source,
                    audioCtx,
                    canvasCtx,
                    frequencyData,
                    running = false,
                    renderer = config.renderer,
                    width = config.width || 360,
                    height = config.height || 360;

                var init = function() {
                    audio = document.getElementById('r0audio');
                    audioCtx = new AudioContext();
                    analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
                    source =  audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
                    source.connect(analyser);
                    analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);
                    analyser.fftSize = 64;
                    frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
                    renderer.init({
                        count: analyser.frequencyBinCount,
                        width: width,
                        height: height
                    });
                };
                this.start = function() {
                    audio.play();
                    running = true;
                    renderFrame();
                };
                this.stop = function() {
                    running = false;
                    audio.pause();
                };
                this.setRenderer = function(r) {
                    if (!r.isInitialized()) {
                        r.init({
                            count: analyser.frequencyBinCount,
                            width: width,
                            height: height
                        });
                    } 
                    renderer = r;
                };
                this.isPlaying = function() {
                    return running;
                }

                var renderFrame = function() {
                    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);
                    renderer.renderFrame(frequencyData);
                    if (running) {
                        requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
                    }
                };

                init();

            };
            var vis = document.querySelectorAll('.initiator');
            var v = null;
                                var lastEl;
                    var lastElparentId;
            for(var i=0; i<vis.length; i++) {
                vis[i].onclick = (function() {

                    return function() {
                        var el = this;
                        var id = el.parentNode.id;

                            if (!v) {
                                v = new Visualization({renderer: renderers[id] });
                            }
                            v.setRenderer(renderers[id]);
                            if (v.isPlaying()) {
                                if (lastElparentId === id) {
                                    v.stop();
                                    el.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
                                } else {
                                    lastEl.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
                                    el.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
                                }

                            }else {

                                v.start();
                                el.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
                            }
                        lastElparentId = id;
                        lastEl = el;
                    };
                })();
            }
        };
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```